# Overwrite the master branch with a orphan branch in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I've created a new orphan branch with `git checkout --orphan orphan-branch` and made a lot of commits on that branch.

Now I want to replace the `master` branch with the newly created `orphan-branch`, all the files and the history of the `master` branch should be replaced by the files and the history of the `orphan` branch. 
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To replace the history and old file of the master branch you need to do a forced update on it.

```
git push origin +your_orphan_branch_name:master
```

Attention: This deletes the whole history on the remote repository for your branch master. But that what you intended to do...

Comment: Don't forget to change your local repo's master branch as well

Answer (score 4):

git branch -m master old-master // rename master to old-master locally

git branch -m orphan_branch master // rename orphan_branch to master locally

git push -f origin master // force-update master on remote

Comment: please add a explanation for this.