# Rewrite master with an orphan branch but keep history

Tags: git

In my project, I started with quite a few commits in the `master` branch. After a couple of releases, I realised that the approach I was taking might not be what we want at all.

The new approach required a complete code rewrite so I decided to start in an orphan branch (`a-new-beginning-branch`). I liked it and eventually, it became my de-facto master branch. Now I want to replace `master` with `a-new-beginning`.

I've found [how to make the current Git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch) but when following the steps shown there, I get the error message `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. I know I could use the `–allow-unrelated-histories` option but I don't really understand what it does and don't want to break things.

I've also found [how to overwrite the master branch with a orphan branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610157/overwrite-the-master-branch-with-a-orphan-branch-in-git) but I don't want to delete the history in my master branch.

Ideally I would like to end up with a lineal history, but if that's not possible, I'll be also happy with some sort of a merge.

[image: git workflow]

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you want to keep the current history of the current `master` branch, with your `a-new-beginning` one.

If you objective is just to have a branch named `master` with the history of your `a-new-beginning` branch, you can perform it this way:

```
git branch -m master master-backup
git push origin :master master-backup

git branch -m a-new-beginning master
git push origin :a-new-beginning master
```

This way, you will update the branches, locally and remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebasing your **master** in your **new Branch** ?

1- `$ git checkout a-new-beginning-branch`

2- `$ git rebase master`

Your new branch now contains both the history of `a-new-beginning-branch` & `master` branch

Answer (score 0):

As you've said you can use `--allow-unrelated-histories`. This option allow to merge data when no commit are common. In this case [how to make the current git branch a master branch discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/make-the-current-git-branch-a-master-branch) looks as our better solution.

We can do then :

```
git checkout better_branch
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git checkout master
git merge better_branch             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

Fist merge get a related history to new branch with old master.
Second merge act new branch data as master data.

You can check merge is ok with a `git diff master..better_branch^` . Diff should be empty.